# Excel: Returning Similar Duplicate Values Across 2 Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A (Master PC) contains postcode sectors and column B (Postcodes) contains postcodes.

I want to know which postcodes in column B are found/repeated in column A.

For example:

B2 (DE45 1DS) falls within A2 (DE45 1) therefore I would like B2 to be highlighted or return a TRUE value.

[image]

Comment: You can find the rows that match A2 with this formula in F2: `=IFERROR(IF(FIND(A$2,B2)>0,"Match"),"")`.  As it is filled down, it will put "Match" in every row where part of column B equals column A.  You'll need to do this in 34 columns to find all the matches. This formula `=IFERROR(IF(FIND(OFFSET($A$2,COLUMN()-6,0),$B2)>0,"Match"),"")` can be filled right and down from F2, and will identify all the matches.  But, as you will see, itthe results take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 1):

As your column E postcodes appear to be column E postcodes "cleaned" to conform with the Master PC schema, you could apply conditional formatting using a formula:

```
=MATCH($E2,$A:$A,0)>0
```

This conditional format should be entered while you have B2:B35 selected or, if you will be adding more data to B, have all of column B selected.  The latter will incur an overhead on calculation time because conditional formats are evaluated whenever recalculation is invoked.